# SQL invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT TIME(ADDTIME(departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(jptl2.run_time)))) AS departure,
       service.line_name AS line,
       bus.registration
FROM vehicle_journey
LEFT JOIN bus ON bus.journey = vehicle_journey.code AND
          ADDTIME(TIME(NOW()), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)) > vehicle_journey.departure AND
          ADDTIME(TIME(NOW()), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)) < ADDTIME(vehicle_journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(jptl.run_time)))
INNER JOIN service ON service.reference = vehicle_journey.service_reference
INNER JOIN vehicle_journey_days ON vehicle_journey_days.journey_reference = vehicle_journey.reference
INNER JOIN journey_pattern ON journey_pattern.reference = vehicle_journey.journey_pattern_reference
INNER JOIN journey_pattern_timing_link jptl ON jptl.section = journey_pattern.journey_pattern_section
INNER JOIN journey_pattern_timing_link jptl2 ON jptl2.section = journey_pattern.journey_pattern_section AND jptl2.ID < jptl.id
WHERE jptl.stop = '1900HA030334' AND vehicle_journey_days.day = 'MondayToFriday'
GROUP BY vehicle_journey.id
```

The above SQL query returns: `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

I Know that this issue is caused by the third `ON` in the `LEFT JOIN bus` clause. How can I rewrite the query so it saves the same purpose and joins based on the same requirements but without the group function error?

Can I just write the `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(jptl.run_time))` as a sub query?
EG: `(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(jptl.run_time)))`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a group function in a `[LEFT] JOIN` condition, because at this stage, the group are still in the process of being constructed (and the contents of these groups depend on the join conditions, so this would create a sort of circular reference).

First construct your groups, then join the table that depends on these groups:

```
SELECT groups.*, bus.registration
FROM (
    SELECT
        TIME(...) AS departure,
        service.line_name AS line,
        ADDTIME(vehicle_journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(jptl.run_time)))
            AS upper_limit,
        vehicle_journey.code
            AS vj_code,
        vehicle_journey.departure
            AS vj_departure
    FROM vehicle_journey
    -- skip "bus" for now
    JOIN service ...
    -- add all remaining JOIN's here
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY vehicle_journey.id
) AS groups
LEFT JOIN bus
    ON bus.journey = vj_code
    AND ADDTIME(TIME(NOW()), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)) > vj_departure
    AND ADDTIME(TIME(NOW()), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)) < upper_limit;
```

You could also simply move the offending condition down to a `HAVING` clause, but this would not return records with no match in `bus` (effectively turning the `LEFT JOIN` into a `INNER JOIN`):

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM vehicle_journey
LEFT JOIN bus ON bus.journey = vehicle_journey.code AND
      ADDTIME(TIME(NOW()), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)) > vehicle_journey.departure
      -- no reference to "SUM(jptl.run_time)" here
JOIN service ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY vehicle_journey.id
-- and here is the reference to "SUM(jptl.run_time)"
HAVING ADDTIME(TIME(NOW()), SEC_TO_TIME(3600))
       < ADDTIME(vehicle_journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(jptl.run_time)))
```